# Solr date range filtering not returning any results

Tags: date, solr, filter, filtering

I'm in my Solr dashboard, trying to test out queries to get items where the search_date field >= NOW. I have the following date field:

`"c_search_date_tdt": "2017-10-08T16:51:33Z"`

However, I'm having issues querying that field.

When I query that field with `c_search_date_tdt:"2017-10-08T16:51:33Z"`, I get 1 result as expected.

However, when I try to filter by that field (in the fq box) like so:

`c_search_date_tdt:[* TO NOW]`

I get zero results.

I also tried this specific filter: `c_search_date_tdt:["2017-10-01T16:51:33Z" TO "2017-10-20T16:51:33Z"]`

but I get zero results for that too.

Comment: i expect that c_search_date_tdt:[* TO *] is working for you, right? could you post your schema related to field c_search_date_tdt

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that I was putting it in the fq field; when I put `c_search_date_tdt:[NOW TO *]` in the q field, I got the results I expected